# Nuget package is not listed on ADO Artifacts, but I can't upload because it already exists?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, azure-devops-artifacts

I have a newly created Feed in Azure DevOps where I'm hosting my Nuget packages.  I uploaded a bunch, but when I tried to download `My.Package.1.0.4` it isn't listed in the feed; neither in VS nor on the web portal.  `My.Package.1.0.5-beta-2` is there, but even in the version list 1.0.4 is not shown.

I figured it just didn't get uploaded - so tried again; when I do, I get the error `Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict - The feed already contains 'My.Package 1.0.4'.`

My question is: where is it hiding?  It doesn't show up in the feed anywhere, but it apparently uploaded successfully.  What do I do now?

Comment: Same here. Uploaded two packages then on the 3rd one, says it exists and it's never been uploaded before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It could happen when package was deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/delete-and-recover-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=nuget#delete-packages-from-azure-artifacts-feeds):

> When you publish a particular version of a package to a feed, that version number is permanently reserved. You cannot upload a newer revision package with that same version number, or delete it and upload a new package at the same version.

You can check it here:

[image]

Comment: Nope, nothing in the Recycle Bin.  It's like the file got uploaded (and can't be re-uploaded because the same version number exists) but for some reason can't be downloaded.  This repo is brand new - nothing has ever been deleted.